# Display both options of ToggleButton in WPF as links with custom styles

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to display two links namely "Entire Content" and "Summary" on a page. I wish to use a ToggleButton so that the relevant information can be displayed by switching between the two options.

However, I wish to display the toggle button options such that both the links are visible at all times and the one which is selected should be highlighted (probably styled with a bold, italic or underline), just to let the user know the currently displayed content.

What would be a good way to achieve this?

Comment: where are the links located, away from the toggle button? also, what controls are you using to display the links. Need a bit more info.

Answer (score 0):

How about using two grouped radio buttons styled to look like toggle buttons.